# how to decrease the size of db file that created by LiteDb after i has deleted about 200 records

Tags: litedb

How to decrease the size of db file that created by LiteDb , after I has deleted about 200 records;
I have seen all issues of the litedb doc, but no satisfactory answer;

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `Rebuild()` method on your database:

```cs
using var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db");
db.Rebuild();
```